# How do I select a local background image for a section in my website?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a background image for this `#title#` section. When I upload the image to some website and paste the link in my CSS like `background: url(www.imagelink.com/image)`it works. However, when I want to do the same thing with a local image for example `background: url(images/folder/image.jpg)`, it doesn't work. Nothing appears in my page when I do it locally. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sarraf Battal Ünal</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT"
      crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- External CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <!--  Google fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@400;700&family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;700;900&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3f441d9c50.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="title">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="my-navbar-container">
        <!-- Nav Bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent">
          <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="images/battalunal-white-final1-removebg-preview1.png" alt="sarraf-logo" />
          </a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarToggler01"
            aria-controls="navbarToggler01"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center navbar-content-div" id="navbarToggler01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Ana Sayfa</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Katalog</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">Kurumsal</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="" class="nav-link">İletişim</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1 id="slogan-h1">Buraya kısa slogan gelecek. Buraya kısa slogan gelecek.</h1>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 title-button-grid">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg col title-button">
                <span class="fa fa-duotone fa-phone"></span> Bize Ulaşın
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg col title-button">
                <span class="fa fa-duotone fa-chart-simple"></span> Güncel Fiyatlar
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <!-- Add image or slider in this column 
          <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup" /> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website is stored on a server if it's a live site. So to the server that the site lives on your file path `images/folder/image.jpg` doesn't get found on the server that the site lives on (because the file is in that location on your machine not your sites machine basically). If your trying to find an alternative to uploading the file to the site you could add it to a sharing system like google cloud and use the link to view the photo as your background image url.

If your site is a local build still and the site lives at /users/sites/mysite and your images live at /users/images you would have to navigate backwards through the files from /mysite to get back to the /users folder then you can use the file path that you have , it can be a bit tricky to get it the first time but once you find your file path you should have no issues recreating the same selector to get photos from the /images/folder folder to display on your site. you can navigate backwards through the folders by using `../` in your url selection. In the above example getting from /mysite back to /users would require your css selector to look like this `url(../../images/folder/image.jpg)` where each of the `../` will take you out of a folder until your pointing to the /users folder then from there you can go into your images folder and find the file your trying to get added.

Comment: I'm not hosting my website currently. It is on my local file system, just like the images.

Comment: you can use `../` to go back a folder to navigate through your sites files, you will have to use `../../` to go back 2 folders for example your selector could look something like this `url(../../../../images/folder/image.jpg)` (this is going out of 4 folders from your sites root directory) depending on the file path that your website lives you will have to navigate all the way out of the site folder and then back into the images path that you have

Answer (score 1):

If the directory that contains your images is outside the directory that contains your css file, then the path should be `url(../images/folder/image.jpg)` instead of `url(images/folder/image.jpg)`. The `../` means to go up one level to the directory that contains the current directory.